# JQuery Bounce effect changing the size of the element

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have a "notification box" like so in CSS;

```
.NotificationsBox
{
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 height:17px;
 width:17px;
 border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;   
 Background-Color: #0099FF;
 border-color: #FFFFFF;
 top:65px;
 left:500px;
}
```

being manipulated with the bounce effect in JQuery;

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".NotificationsBox").effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow");
});
</script>
```

HTML;

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="NotifyMe">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="NotificationLabel2" runat="server"  
Text='<%# Bind("[Notifications]") %>'
CssClass="NotificationsBox"  />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

The bounce effect works fine except that the width of the box changes during the bounce effect- it's set in the CSS to be a small box at 17px x 17px.. Currently there is a '1' in the box and the animation seems to shrink the width to fit the '1' only then grows back to normal size after the effect finishes - I've tried using padding in CSS to pad the sides of the 1 in the box but that had no effect - any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: How does your HTML look ? When i try it it seems to work fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/j7Lzds7n/

Comment: not sure why it was doing it, found a solution by using jQuery to set the width/height before the bounce like so..               <script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        var div = $(".NotificationsBox");
        div.animate({ height: '17px', opacity: '1' }, "fast");
        div.animate({ width: '17px', opacity: '1' }, "fast");
        div.effect("bounce");
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-height` and `min-width` to the `.NotificationsBox` style.

```
min-height:17px;
min-width:17px;
```